# How to retain revision history when cloning a Conda environment?

Tags: conda, clone, revision-history

When I clone a Conda environment

```
conda create --name thenewenv --clone theorigenv
```

I noticed the revision history of `theorigenv` is lost as seen by

```
conda activate thenewenv
conda list -r
```

How can I clone a Conda environment and retain the original environment's revision history?

Comment: Please consider either accepting the answer or providing feedback as to why it is unsatisfactory.

Answer (score 4):

It appears that copying the `conda-meta/history` file from the original environment will retain the history

```bash
cp envs/theorigenv/conda-meta/history envs/thenewenv/conda-meta/history
```

It even seems to work with reverting to earlier revisions, e.g.,

```bash
conda install -n thenewenv --revision <n>
```